# Running regressions where coefficients change over time

Tags: regression, econometrics, finance, regression-strategies

I'm trying to predict monthly stock price returns using 93 features that I think may be relevant.  I have data for these features from 1990 to 2015.  For each month from 1990 to 2015 I run a regression where the independent variable is next month's price return and the independent variables are these features.  To be clear, I'm running a single regression with all the data, not one regression per month.  Using Lasso and 10 fold cross validation I identify that 48 of these features are significant.

However, its very clear that some of these features were a lot more important in the past than they are now.  For example, the ratio book to market value has a very high t-stat during the 1990's but as people started doing more statistical trading, the t-stat decays over time.  Many of the other features have the same problem.

My question is how do I accommodate for the time varying nature of these coefficients so I can use the model to predict future returns today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are surely many different answers, I'd start out simple and think about a $time$ x $feature$ interaction in the model regression model.  This would allow the features to have different effects at different points in time and you might find that earlier time x feature interactions are not statistically significant, while more recent interactions are.

You might also want to consider the use of splines to help model the $time$ x $feature$ heterogeneity.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very helpful.  After reading more about this, it seems that I would not be able to use time as a continuous variable (e.g fractional years since 1990).  Instead I could create 5 year buckets for time so I could use a 1 or 0 for each bucket in the interaction.  Any thoughts on finding further reading on this?  How about weighted least squares, using time to weight the variables?